# an odd blank page before appendix

Tags: page

```
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents} % shows appendix at page 12, but it links to page 11.
\tableofcontents

\section{AA}

\begin{enumerate}
\item BB\ref{apx:api} % points at page 11.
\end{enumerate}

\appendix
\section{Appendix} % starts at page 12. but page 11 is blank.
\label{apx:api}
\centerline{\includegraphics[page=1,scale=0.8]{api.pdf}}
\includepdf[pages={2-}, scale=0.8]{api.pdf}
```

When it comes to the appendix, there is a blank page before it (page 11), and both `\ref` and table-of-contents refers to that blank page (table-of-contents does have a correct page number page 12)

[image: the odd blank page 11]

Comment: You are probably more likely to get help if you post a full minimal example instead of a sniplet. Both document class and preamble is relevant to solve this issue. Preferably post a full compilable example others can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif I think it depends on the certain text, because after I use `geometry` to change`margin`, this Oreo cream disappeared. That's why it is odd.

Comment: please tell us which document class you employ. Also, please indicate how full page 10 is. And what's the reference to Oreo cream about?

Comment: Without more details we cannot help. All out of crystal balls, sorry.

Comment: @Mico would a local view enough? I have attached it, and I think page 10 is not full at all. The Oreo cream is white between black, like a blank page between text-filled pages.

Comment: The "local view" is definitely not sufficient. What we need to see is the code that gives rise to the undesirable behavor.

Comment: In book class, for example, appendices are treated a chapters and always start on a odd page.  Try \let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage